# Summation method laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two fields, `views`, which just counts views, and `add_to_views`, a number that we add to views.

I need to display the sum of these numbers in the blade. Of course, you can just do this and everything will work.

```
{{ $article->views + $article->add_to_views }} Views
```

But I want to make the summation function separately and output the already ready number

Here is what I am trying to do, in the `Article` model itself I create a method

```
public function getTotalViews() {
        return $this->views + $this->add_to_views;
    }
```

Further in the controller I call it

```
$article = Article::where('id')->first();
$article->getTotalViews();
```

And I bring to the blade

```
{{ $article->getTotalViews() }} Views
```

But I get the error

`Call to a member function getTotalViews() on null`

Comment: `where('id')` expects a value for that property. Ie `where('id', $id)`. Also you can use `firstOrFail()` instead just `first()`, or you can use `find($id)` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the ID for the `Article` that you're trying to get so it is null.
It should actually be something like:

`$article = Article::where('id', 1)->first();`

Or alternatively, you could do

`$article = Article::find(1);`

For a longer explanation on the find method:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models